# Using PHP in HTML select and get data from a INCLUDE file

Tags: php, html

I am looking to include a HTML snippet into a PHP variable however, it currently just displays it separately.

The aim of this is to have the values of the HTML file to be displayed. This code currently displays the Select and the Option I have but outputs the HTML file as if it was separate.

*PHP:*

```
  $input .= "<select name='address_country' class='form-control' required>";
  $input .= "<option value='".$value_columns[$x]."'>No Change</option>";
  $input .= include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DOCROOT."includes/country_select.html");
  $input .= "</select>";
```

*HTML:*

```
<option value="United States">United States</option>
<option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood well, but as I understood, you want to put the content of "includes/country_select.html"

into a $input?

If yes, try:
[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead of include()